# Calculate Customer Derived Trade Areas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, business-analyst

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 with Advanced license and access to Spatial Analyst.
I do not have access to the Business Analyst Desktop extension, and Business Analyst Online does not have this capability.

This is a shame, as the [Customer Derived Trade Areas tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000z00000105000000) (with a nice wizard interface) is exactly what I need.

Was wondering if anyone has an alternative way of achieving this with perhaps a nice model in modelbuilder or a python script?

Comment: Are you only interested in existing tools or scripts, or are you looking for steps to solve the problem and potentially create your own?

Comment: Hey @ChrisW - Ideally the former.  I would have expected someone else has already encountered this issue and want to avoid re-inventing the wheel (dont make me code!)